# Always use one GPU

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, hybrid-graphics, gpu

I got a Linux-Box with 2 GPU (intel and nvidia). I'm using bumblebee (and primus) for using the nvidia card, but I'm quite far from be really satisfied.
I would like to know if there is a way to disable intel gpu and make my system use only the nvidia card.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Comment: I was following your answer but it is vanished... however, this new link you posted is too generic, there is no real answer.

Comment: Yeah, my answer was wrong, after some more research I found that you don't have two separate cards, you have one card that is a duct tape two cards. I deleted the answer because there was no way to recover it. Primus cards, can't access the nvidia card by it's self. They are hard wired with no access to the nvidia card at all except though the bumblebee "hack". You sir, appear to need a new laptop (or live with the sub par performance).

Comment: Got it... but since it is possible to use all the power of the nvidia gpu under win then I guess there is a way to do it on linux...

Comment: Currently no, "some day" maybe. Though this type of cheap hardware usually doesn't end up getting supported very well. It could, if it gains a lot of popularity.